# Webdings to Unicode

Tags: xslt, unicode, fonts

I have to transform an XML-file via XSLT, that contains characters of different font-types, such as Symbol, Wingdings, Webdings, etc.

The input looks like this:

```
<p><schar font="Webdings" nr="0081">&#129;</schar></p>
```

To handle it, I wrote a function as follows:

```
<xsl:function name="resolveWebdingsFont" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="hexcode" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="fallback" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="hexkey" select="upper-case(replace($hexcode, '^0*(.+)', '$1'))" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newchar" select="$webdings-character-map[@hex = $hexkey]/@to" as="xs:string?"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="if ($newchar) then $newchar else $fallback"/>
</xsl:function>
```

I put the character-map in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="webdings-character-map" as="element(char)+">
    ....
    <char hex="81" to="&#x1F6BA;"/>
    <!-- Womens symbol -->
    ...
</xsl:variable>
```

I call the function like this:

```
<xsl:template match="schar">
    <span data-type="schar">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@font = 'Symbol'">
                <xsl:value-of select="dy:resolveSymbolFont(@nr, .)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@font = 'Webdings'">
                <xsl:value-of select="dy:resolveWebdingsFont(@nr, .)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            ...
         </xsl:choose>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

The desired output is a `<span>` with the unicode representation as its value and this is working well for font-types like Symbol etc.

To map also all the Webdings characters correctly, I would need a complete list of all Webdings characters and their unicode representation.

With unicode version 7.0 (Jun, 2014) they have been integrated. But the specification says:

> The well-known “Zapf Dingbats” set is encoded comprehensively in the
>   Dingbats block, U+2700 ..U+27BF. Other sets of dingbats, such as the
>   Wingdings and Webdings sets, are encoded in various symbol blocks, but
>   the majority are found in the Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
>   block, U+1F300..U+1F5FF."

As far as I understood one would have to look through every block to get a complete list of all characters and their equivalent; but this is what I'd like to avoid. And even if I would find a symbol that looks similar to a certain Webdings symbol, I can't be sure it's the one that's intended officially to represent it. Others don't even look similar but are intended to represent them.

I couldn't find any official document for that.
Does there exist an official mapping from Webdings to unicode?

Or is there even a totally different/better approach to convert special characters to unicode in XSLT?

Comment: Have a look at [Webdings and Wingdings Symbol Collection](http://unicode.org/~asmus/web-wing-ding-ext.pdf).

Comment: just check the unicode website. http://www.unicode.org/charts -> "dingbats" -> off you go.

Comment: Now there's some information you really should have put in your post before hitting the "post" button. Hit up the edit link, put that information in your question, and then delete the comment (and then I can delete mine too, since all three should be entirely unnecessary after your edit)

Comment: So what is your question?  This still looks to me like you are looking to find a book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource.

Answer (score 0):

> To map also all the Webdings characters correctly, I would need a
>   complete list of all Webdings characters and their unicode
>   representation.

AFAIK, you just need to add 61440 to the decimal code value. In your example, `&#129;` would become `&#61569;`. This applies to Webdings and Windings/Windings2/Windings3 fonts - I am not sure about others.

Comment: I think this does not work.
The decimal value for the women's symbol is `128698`.
`61569` is a value of the private use area.

Comment: @bauz I might be out of date on this. Have you tried adding the difference between the two, i.e. 128698 - 129?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be such an easy and clear order. But this seems logic, as some Webdings symbols have been integrated and others have been merged with existing unicode characters.

Comment: @bauz If there's no general algorithm to convert the numerical codes, you will have to use a lookup table. But then your question *would* be off-topic for SO.

Comment: Ok, if no generic solution is found, I'll accept the question to get closed.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking of deleting my answer as it obviously does not apply to the current state of things.